# How to overcome performance issue when converting utf8mb4 to latin1?

Tags: mysql, performance, alter, iso-8859-1, utf8mb4

By my ignorance, I have altered a few tables without specifying collation.
That caused changed columns, which used to be `latin1` characters, to be changed to `utf8mb4`.

This brought HUGE performance loss running joins. And when I say HUGE I mean fraction of a second changed to one hour or more!

So I have made an other request to convert it back to latin1.

And here comes the problem. Mere 60k row table, with ONE utf8mb4 column of 64 characters required 10 hours to complete. No, it is not a mistake. TEN hours. And my even bigger problem is that I have other tables that have millions of rows giving me ETA in years from today!

So now, I wonder what my options are because I can't afford having these tables to be read-only for longer than one day time.

I know that MYSQL `ALTER` creates a copy of a table. It makes sense because this is field size change, so I doubt I have an option to use `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`.

If I cannot do INPLACE then I cannot use `LOCK=NONE` option.

**Why in the world `utf8mb4` -> `latin1` conversion could make such a big impact?**

Note that the converted column is indexed, and this may be a reason for the impact!

ANY suggestion or a link would be greatly appreciated!
Maybe the solution would be to drop index (to avoid funky multibyte issue in the index conversion,) do fast alter, and then add an index?

Thanks in advance for any serious suggestion and I suspect I may not find much of a help because of the uniqueness of it.

*EDIT*

```
 jobs | CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `auto_inc_key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `request_entered_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `hash_id` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `host` char(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `state` char(12) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `aggregation_job_id` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `aggregation_job_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`auto_inc_key`),
  KEY `host` (`host`),
  KEY `hash_id` (`hash_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`request_entered_timestamp`),
  KEY `request_entered_timestamp_idx` (`request_entered_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9068466 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

 jobs_archive | CREATE TABLE `jobs_archive` (
  `auto_inc_key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `request_entered_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `hash_id` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `host` char(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `state` char(12) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`auto_inc_key`),
  KEY `host` (`host`),
  KEY `hash_id` (`hash_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`request_entered_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=239432 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

(taken from PROCEDURE, but you catch the drift...)
INSERT INTO jobs_archive (SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, request_entered_timestamp, starttime) > days));
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and also the `SELECT ... JOIN...`  It sounds like something else is going on other than what you have described.

Comment: @RickJames Posted. Note that I am working the `hash_id` field. Also note that the names were changed so things may not looking logical in case of meaning. Also note that this was working for us for last few years. The performance got hit only when I changed `latin1` to `utf8mb4` and after changing `job` to `latin1` the performance came back to normal (I did not convert the `jobs_archive` yet in production because it is way too big.)

Comment: What is `starttime`?  (With a suitable change to the `WHERE`, and the addition of an index, the `INSERT..SELECT` should run a lot faster.)

Comment: I need to see the JOIN -- that is probably where the collation issue is.

Comment: Will you be DELETEing the 'archived' rows?  Or leaving them in `jobs`?

Comment: Re "TEN hours":  Please show us the `ALTER`.

Comment: "Note that the converted column is indexed" -- Which column?

Comment: Actually the simplest query that takes so much longer is the one I have posted after EDIT. That is that `INSERT INTO jobs_archive`

Comment: @RickJames `hash_id` is the one that got converted and we have a problem with. The contents of the table above came from the current state of the table, but before the `hash_id` was `utf8mb4`. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is `days`?  Is `starttime` the same as `start_time`?

Comment: @RickJames These are PROCEDURE variables. Basically it tells to copy all rows that are older than this number of days.

Comment: Avoid functions; put the column on one side of the formula.  Something like `WHERE request_entered_timestamp < starttime - INTERVAL days DAY`.  (I may have the formula wrong.)  You have an index to support this variant; no index helps your version.

Comment: @RickJames This I cannot change and this wasn't a problem before the `latin1` -> `utf8mb4` conversion. I won't be able to justify this change to the management